# Is there any way to access the accountid inside the offchain worker?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, frontier

I am coding a pallet in which I need to know who I am inside a offchain worker to check if I should send a transaction or not. Right now I have access to the account in the `send_signed_transaction` callback but it doesn`t seem like an elegant way.

This is what I would need:

```
    #[pallet::hooks]
impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
    fn offchain_worker(now: BlockNumberFor<T>) {
        let signer = Signer::<T, T::AuthorityId>::all_accounts();

        if !signer.can_sign() {
            log::warn!(
                target: LOG_TARGET,
                "Skipping offchain worker because no local account is available."
            );
            return;
        }

        if !sp_io::offchain::is_validator() {
            return;
        }

        // What i need
        let who = signer.iam();

        let validators = Validators::<T>::get();
        let approvedValidators = ApprovedValidators::<T>::get();

        if (!approvedValidators.contains(&who)) {
            return;
        }

        if (validators.contains(&who)) {
            return;
        }

        signer.send_signed_transaction(|_account| Call::add_validator_again {
            validator_id: _account.id.clone(),
        });

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your rationale is starting from the assumption that **only** OCWs will be calling `add_validator_again`. That is not safe. Malicious actors could also call them while "impersonating" an OCW.

Regardless of the checks you are making inside your OCW logic, you also need to make sure that the execution of `add_validator_again` is only granted to keys belonging to `ApprovedValidators`.

You could implement a `SignedExtension` with some logic similar to this:

```
impl<T: Config + Send + Sync> SignedExtension for AuthorizeOcw<T>
where
    T::Call: Dispatchable<Info = DispatchInfo> + GetCallMetadata,
{
    type AccountId = T::AccountId;
    type Call = T::Call;
    type AdditionalSigned = ();
    type Pre = ();
    const IDENTIFIER: &'static str = "AuthorizeOcw";

    fn additional_signed(&self) -> sp_std::result::Result<(), TransactionValidityError> {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn validate(
        &self,
        who: &Self::AccountId,
        call: &Self::Call,
        _info: &DispatchInfoOf<Self::Call>,
        _len: usize,
    ) -> TransactionValidity {
        let md = call.get_call_metadata();

        if md.palet_name == "my_pallet" && 
           md.function_name == "add_validator_again" &&
           <ApprovedValidators<T>>::contains_key(who) &&
           !<Validators<T>>::contains_key(who)
        {
            Ok(Default::default())
        } else {
            Err(InvalidTransaction::Call.into())
        }
    }
}
```

Transactions with calls to `add_validator_again` that are coming from accounts that don't belong to `ApprovedValidators` (or that do belong to `Validators`) will never make it into the Tx Pool.

---

In regards to the `signer.iam()` that you alluded to, unfortunately the public APIs exposed by `frame_system::offchain::Signer` don't really offer anything of that nature.

But with the solution described above, you don't really need it.

Sure, most OCWs will "waste" transactions that never get executed. But that is actually the right security model, since unauthorized actors could also attempt this and they must not be successful.